# Change default drive letter assignment

Tags: external-hard-drive, windows-server-2008-r2, drive-letter

I have a server running SBS 2011, and we have a rotating disk backup solution using Comodo Backup. The backup is configured to back up to the H:, however, two of our five disks ALWAYS have a drive letter assignment of G. I have changed this in Disk Management numerous times, however, I am tired of having to do this every Tuesday and Friday.

How can I force Windows to assign specific drive letters to certain drives, or just force Windows to use the H: as the first attempted drive letter for all external media plugged into the server?

Thanks in advance for any assistance on this matter.

**NOTE** Tagged this with Windows Server 2008 R2 since SBS 2011 is essentially the same thing under the hood.

Comment: It is better to manually assign a drive letter farther down the list, like R, once this is done for each device on each PC, windows will remember this and mount the drives as R each time they are plugged in. You would have to change Comodo setting. This usually solves problems of assigning drive letters when they are too close to other mounted drives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around the issue by changing the drive letter that was referenced. I knew I could do this, but I had to change the reference in several places, so I was hoping I could just force the drive letter with a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do that:

- plug in the drive
- go to Device Manager (winkey+break > hardware > Device Manager)
- remove it
- unplug it
- plug it in again: here Windows will reinstall drivers and will assign a available letter to it